# Minecraft Item dragging

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

On Minecraft, I was just playing on my server when I was forced to quit and restart my game. I joined my server, and the next thing I knew, I couldn't drag and drop items, shift click items, and a few other problems. I tried reinstalling Minecraft but it didn't change. It also moves the number of how many items in the slot up a notch. When I drag the item I am holding onto another item, it drifts back to the slot it was in. I can't right click any item either. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You have Touchscreen Mode enabled. To turn it off again, go to <kbd>Options...</kbd> > <kbd>Controls...</kbd> then set <kbd>Touchscreen Mode</kbd> `OFF`.